# Derive Initial investment based on Compounded returns

Tags: investing, calculation, investment-strategies, rate-of-return

I know the investment instruments, their average yearly returns, the duration of investment and the target corpus. Based on the target corpus and the average returns, I want to reverse engineer and find the initial investment required to reach the target corpus. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "target corpus" I assume you mean target *value*. The formula for future value given a compounding rate of return `r` and a time period `t` is:

```
FV = PV * (1+r)^t
```

So to solve for PV just divide by the compounding effect:

```
PV = FV / ((1+r)^t)
```

But note that with most investments there exists *risk*, meaning some level of probability that the actual returns fluctuate from the target returns. So to say that the initial amount is "required" to get the target may not be completely accurate. You may end up with more or less from the target, but with that inital investment, the specified target should be *expected* (what you'll get on average, with some risk).